# How to order, group, mutate in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to **data.table** & trying to replicate some **dplyr** code but not getting same results when I **mutate** columns.

**libs**

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
```

**df**

```
test_df <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1234, 5678, 5678),
           date = c("2021-10-10","2021-10-10", "2021-8-10", "2021-8-15"),
           Amount  = c(54767, 96896, 34534, 79870)) %>% 
  
  mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

**dplyr code:**

```
test_df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Amt_first = first(Amount),
         Amt_last = last(Amount)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

results:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
     id date       Amount Amt_first Amt_last
  <dbl> <date>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1  5678 2021-08-10  34534     34534    79870
2  5678 2021-08-15  79870     34534    79870
3  1234 2021-10-10  54767     54767    96896
4  1234 2021-10-10  96896     54767    96896
```

**data.table attempt** (returns me nothing):

```
setDT(test_df)[order(date),
             `:=`(Amt_first = data.table::first(Amount),
                   Amt_last = data.table::last(Amount)), 
             by = id]
```

I am not sure what is wrong, it seems its not selecting any columns but I as am mutating columns so ideally it should return all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in [data.table's FAQ - 2.23](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-do-i-have-to-type-dt-sometimes-twice-after-using-to-print-the-result-to-console).
You just need to add an extra `[]` at the end of your code:

```
setDT(test_df)[order(date),
             `:=`(Amt_first = data.table::first(Amount),
                   Amt_last = data.table::last(Amount)), 
             by = id][]

     id       date Amount Amt_first Amt_last
1: 1234 2021-10-10  54767     54767    96896
2: 1234 2021-10-10  96896     54767    96896
3: 5678 2021-08-10  34534     34534    79870
4: 5678 2021-08-15  79870     34534    79870
```